# AJAX & jQuery - Form Data is being sent correctly, but not being inserted. Why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am try to insert data from $.ajax post

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal form-groups validate" enctype="multipart/from-data" id="validated_form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default" data-collapsed="0">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <i class="entypo-user"></i> &nbsp;Customer Information              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="col-sm-5">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">SKU_No</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-code"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" id="SKU_No" class="form-control" name="SKU_No"
                                    value="" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
....................

    </form>
```

My Parameters are going fine from form

this is My ajax call which is sending data

```
  $.ajax({
         data: data,
         type: "post",
         url: "Product_DB.php",
         success: function(data){
              alert(data);
         }
});
```

[image]

this is my php file

```
<?php
         if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "pharmacy";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
               die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 


            $sql = "insert into `pharmacy`.`tblproduct` ( SKU_No, Batch_No, Strip_No, SAP_Code, Item_Name, Item_Qty, Purchase_Price, Deal%, Created_Date, Modified_Date, IsDeleted)         
            values ('".$_POST["SKU_No"]."','".$_POST["Batch_No"]."' ,'".$_POST["Strip_No"]."' , '".$_POST["SAP_Code"]."','".$_POST["Item_Name"]."' ,'".$_POST["Qty"]."' ,'".$_POST["Purchase_Price"]."' , '".$_POST["Discount"]."','".date("Y-m-d")."' ,'".date("Y-m-d")."' ,'0' )";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
               echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
               echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
            $conn->close();
         }
      ?>
```

in response I am not getting any msg or error .. the php file is not hitting .
I also try to 
How can i track the issue ? Any Idea

Comment: Can you provide your ajax call also?

Comment: your JS / ajax code ?

Comment: `$_POST["Discount%"]` would appear to be incorrect as also would the column `Deal%`

Comment: rectified that . still issue is there

Comment: are you sure that $_POST["submit"] exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you're posting `data` to your php file and checking `isset($_POST['submit'])` which is surely not set. Try this

```
$.ajax({
         data: {'submit': data}, //Align your submit with the data your're posting
         type: "post",
         url: "Product_DB.php",
         success: function(data){
              alert(data);
         }
});
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, try changing the *data* line with `data:"submit="+data`,

Answer (score 0):

Has I said in comment, `$_POST['submit']` is undefined, so your test `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` fail and the rest of your code is not execute.

Because you need every parameters to continue, I suggest you to test if every parameters in the request is set  :

```
if(isset($_POST["SKU_No"]) && isset($_POST["Batch_No"]) && ...isset($_POST["Discount"]))
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST["SKU_No"], $_POST["Batch_No"], ..., $_POST["Discount"]))
```

instead of

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
```